# Why doesn't synclient TapButton3=2 work for me (three finger middle click)?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have a 2012 Vaio SVS13 and I cannot figure out why I can't get multitouch to work, particularly three finger tapping for middle click (and of less importance, pinch to zoom). Two finger scrolling and two finger tapping work. With the command, xinput list-props 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' I have the setting Synaptics Capabilities (320):    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 so I don't see why my touchpad shouldn't have the capability (it also worked in Windows). I have tried synclient TapButton3=2 in terminal (which I realize only works in the current session) and I'm getting no results.